# Select list values are passed as null

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I've created a jsp with a html form, that when submitted goes to a servlet.

In my form, I've got a multiple select list, populated with values.

In my servlet, I want to get the values do some modifications.

When I try to access the parameter values in the servlet, they are all displayed as null.

Snippet from servlet:

```
String[] withAccess = req.getParameterValues("withAccess");

        for(int i = 0; i < withAccess.length; i++ )
            System.out.println(withAccess[i]);
```

This code prints "null" N times, where N is the array size.

So what is the problem?

I can't figure it out.

All elements are selected before I click on submit.

My html file, where the form resides:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>

 <jsp:useBean id="bean2" class="models.JDBCModelAccess" scope="page"/>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Insert title here</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <form action="ModelConfiguration.do" method="post">

<label for="models">Models:</label>
<select name="models" id="models" onChange="makeRequest()">
<c:forEach var="model" items="${bean2.models}">
        <option>${model}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>

<label for="withoutAccess">Users without access to the model:</label>
<select name="withoutAccess" id="withoutAccess"size="5" multiple="multiple">      </select>

<label for="withAccess">Users with access to the model</label>
<select name="withAccess" id="withAccess" size="5" multiple="multiple"></select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="selectAll(withoutAccess,withAccess,true)">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have any options in those listboxes at all. I think you're filling them using JavaScript somehow and doing it wrong in there. You should instead debug your JS code and reframe your question. This is totally unrelated to JSP/Servlet.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure where the error was. I was utilizing my selectAll() function, and I hadn't put the options.value =..., so only the text appeared, but the values weren't passed to the servlet. Thank you

Comment: I have no idea what the `selectAll()` function does. This is not part of standard JS API and is thus a homegrown function. It's not possible to answer this question without seeing your JS code.

Answer (score 0):

You have no `<option>`s inside your `<select "withAccess" ...>` tag.

You're getting 5 "items" because you have `size="5"`, but they're all empty.

Try this:

```
<select name="withAccess" id="withAccess" size="5" multiple="multiple">
    <option>User 1</option>
    <option>User 2</option>
    <option>User 3</option>
    <option>User 4</option>
    <option>User 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Unselected options are not passed at all.